# How to prevent the cache memory from being cleared when updating my app in xamarin

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

I need the cache memory of my application not to be deleted when updating it.

I need to retrieve session tokens. I used several methods like GetAccountsAsync. Since I use Microsoft authentication but when I update it returns null. As with the MonkeyCache tool, they work normally, but when I refresh the app, the token disappears.

In `AppDelegate` and `MainActivity` I have this:

```cs
Barrel.ApplicationId = NSBundle.MainBundle.BundleIdentifier;
```

App class

```cs
accessToken = Barrel.Current.Get<string>("access_token");

//if (accounts.Count() > 0)
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
{
    Helpers.Settings.IsLoged = true;
}
```

Comment: Please provide more details, because the current state of your question isn't sufficient to clearly understand what you're trying to do and where it fails. Do you want to persist the authentication token? You can store that kind of information in the [Secure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage?tabs=android).

Comment: What do you mean by "cache memory"?  Are you specifically talking about `MonkeyCache`?

Comment: The different platforms have different behaviors. For the android, the cache folder will keep when the app update.